# Cannot programmatically add content to simple HTML DIV Element in XML view

Tags: sapui5

I have a simple XML view (fragment) like this:

```xml
<html:div id="holder"></html:div>
```

I want to add content programmatically like this:

```js
var holder = this.byId("holder");
var label = new sap.m.Label({
    text: "Label"
});

holder.addContent(label);
```

Effect is nothing, no error, no added content.
Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `content` is not an aggregation (an easy mistake to make, since `content` usually *is* an aggregation).

`sap.ui.core.HTML`'s `content` metadata object is a **property** of type *string*. From [the jsdoc](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/HTML.js#L77):

> HTML content to be displayed, defined as a string.

You will need to use a different container for your label, such as `sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout`, or you could just use raw HTML to stick in your `holder` object, rather than that `sap.m.Label` type.

[Here](http://output.jsbin.com/wuxeronohe/1/edit) is a jsbin that takes the XML view part of this question out of the equation.

**Note:** See @hirse's comment below for an important distinction when using `html:div` in XML views

Comment: Although I agree with the answer, note that the XML in the question does not create a Control of `sap.ui.core.HTML`, but rather an actual HTML element, so @schnoedel's answer is closer to the question.

Comment: @hirse Thanks, learned something new. I'll edit my question to draw attention to that point

Comment: xhtml, svg and pure text nodes in an XMLView are just copied into the div of the View when the View gets rendered: [XMLTemplateProcessor](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/XMLTemplateProcessor.js#L183) puts them as string in the aResult which will be assigned to XMLView._aParsedContent and [XMLViewRenderer](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLViewRenderer.js#L66) just writes strings in the _aParsedContent array directly to to the RenderManager. Controls are handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML element and the UI5 Controls are not directly compatible. UI5 Controls are JavaScript objects that have a render function. The render function creates a html fragment on demand. That html fragment ist then inserted into the page.

I have never tried it, but a solution could be to use the [`placeAt()`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#placeAt) method of your label:

```js
label.placeAt("holder");
```

If you are using an XML View, the *holder* id will be prefixed. Then you should use something like this:

```js
label.placeAt(this.getView().createId("holder"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get DOM element of UI5 control by using [getDomRef](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#getDomRef) of `sap.ui.core.Element` class.

Then add your content to this DOM element by using `placeAt()`

[Here](http://jsbin.com/jahavo/edit?html,js,output) is working example.